# Javascript. Элемент с обработчиками событий

Tags: javascript, jquery, ооп

Доброго времени суток,
Возник вопрос по поводу javascript: 
У меня есть конструкция

```
(function($){

    var defaults = {
        param1:null,
        param2:null
    };

    var methods = {
        // инициализация плагина
        init:function(params) {

            var options = $.extend({}, defaults, params);

            $(this).append('<button class="addbtn"></button>');

            $(document).on('click','.addbtn',function(){
                 $(this).append(button.html+input.html);
            });


        }
    };

    var button = {
        html: '<button class="btn">Кнопка</button>'
    };

    var input = {
        html: '<input type="text" class="input" value="" />'
    };

    var actions ={
        clicked:function(){
            alert('clicked');
        },
        hover:function(){
            alert('hover');
        }
    };

    $.fn.JPlugin = function(method){
        if ( methods[method] ) {
            return methods[ method ].apply( this, Array.prototype.slice.call( arguments, 1 ));
        } else if ( typeof method === 'object' || ! method ) {
            return methods.init.apply( this, arguments );
        } else {
            $.error( 'Метод "' +  method + '" не найден в плагине jQuery.mySimplePlugin' );
        }
    };
})(jQuery);
```

На страницу добавляется кнопка и текстовое поле. Как можно инициализировать автоматически к этим объектам события из другой переменной. Например для нажатия на кнопку и поле определить `actions.clicked` а для наведения `actions.hover`.

Answer (score 0):

Можно сделать вот так:

```
var button = {
  el:function(){
    return $('<button>',{class:"btn",text:'Кнопка'}).on('click',function(){actions.clicked();});
  },
  init:function(){
    return this.el();
  }
}
```

а вместо

```
$(this).append(button.html+input.html);
```

сделать так

```
$(this).append(button.init());
```